# Crystal Reports are not working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

When i execute crystal report it gives an error
Could not load file or assembly 'crdb_adoplus, Version=9.1.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

Comment: Have you seen this discussion on the CR support site: http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1430708 ? It doesn't look very positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Place this code in your app.config

   ```xml
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.2"/>
   </startup>
   ```
2. If it would not work then download Crystal Report Runtime from this link http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_1.msi
3. If again Crystal Report create some problem then right click on your project, open Properties, open Debug tab and check option Enable Unmanaged code debugging.

Comment: thanks buddy this option worked for me
Option Enable Unmanned code debugging.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running .Net 4 in VS2010, then you may need to add the following to your .config file (configuration section):

```xml
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

If this doesn't work, then you need to upgrade to Crystal Report for VS2010 from [this link](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp).

Comment: thanks for your answer it works one or two times then no exception visual studio halted

Comment: @FaheemShehzad: then you need to need to upgrade to the VS2010 version of CR. I have added a link to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in app config

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">  </startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have visual studio 2010 in your system then crystall report is not install because there is no any crystal report with visual studio 2010.for open the crystal or .rpt file install the sap crystal report 2010.It willl downloaded from sap object websit.