# CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException:Load report failed. The document has not opened

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have method and I am using crystal-decision report and its throwing an inner exception. How do I fix this issue? I have seen similar topic, but mine does not really solve similar problem as I have attempted to do the same. Please see my logic below and screen shot for more detail. In another words my load method does not open.

```cs
// Controller
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AdvertReport(FormCollection fc)
{
    DataSet ds = obIlReports.Generate_AdvertDetailsReport();
    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Tbl_TrainingAcademy";

    if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
        rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/AdvertReport.rpt");
        rptH.Load(); // The document do not open error is thrown here.
        rptH.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();


        Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "AdvertReport.pdf");
    }
    return View();
}
```

```cs
// Ilreport here with store procedure.
public class ReportsMaster : IlReports
{
    public DataSet Generate_AdvertDetailsReport()
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB"].ToString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            // Handling Exception
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetAdvertReport", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(ds);

                if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    return ds;
                }
                else
                {
                    return ds = null;
                }

            }
            catch(Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                ds.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
// ConnectionString
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB" connectionString="Data Source=GcobaniM-L\SQLEXPRESS; DataBase=eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What error is being thrown? Please [edit] your question to include it

Comment: Here i seem to understand a bit as to why, busy now trying to fix using crystalreport to fully installed on my target IDE. Also i notice i didnt map the datasource that points to my correct table for store procedure to run why, so now im getting conflix error of assembly.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem i had was simple, i created report file without having an extension report like crystal report install for Microsoft Visual Studio. Here is the link for Windows for your compatibility.

https://www.sap.com/cmp/td/sap-crystal-reports-visual-studio-trial.html?trial=%2F%2Fwww.sap.com%2Fregistration%2Ftrial.9a4afb3b-7eaa-42af-98ce-abeae5deb784.html

2. After the installation of this software, the Visual Studio will have Reporting. See my screen shot for idea or clue.
   [image]
3. Make sure your VS is closed until the software is done.
4. Then you create your report and give a its path based on your project application.
5. If you get an exception like one below;

[Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338805/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crystaldecisions-crystalreports-engine)

6. Follow the steps as mentioned from the forum and your application should work, if not troubleshoot.