# Error comes while in Crystal report while running the project online

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am working on asp.net application where i have to show the crystal report. but my Project running online is showing the following error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified/
```

I have added the dll file of crystal report in bin folder. But error is still showing. Please help me someone.

Comment: Check 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001310/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crystaldecisions-reportappserver-clientdoc, 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697852/crystal-reports-are-not-working-in-visual-studio-2010 and 3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130508/cannot-load-file-or-assembly-crystal-decisions-windows-forms-version-13-0-2000

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough placing a dll into bin folder.

Look at this page: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

- Into development environment you must run Crystal Reports developer version for  Visual Studio: **Install Executable - Support pack 15**
- Into deployment environmento you must run Crystal Reports runtime: **MSI 64 bit - 64bit.msi**

> Please note: To integrate "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for
>   Microsoft Visual Studio" into VS 2010 or 2012 (SP 7 and higher) or VS
>   2013 (SP 9 or higher) or VS 2015 RC (SP14) - VS 2015 (fully - SP 15),
>   you must run the Install Executable. Running the MSI will not fully
>   integrate Crystal Reports into VS. MSI files by definition are for
>   runtime distribution only. By default Windows 10 does not install the
>   3.5 framework, CR for VS still needs it. Select it by "Turn Windows feature on or off" and choose both options.